# Getting the mac address of the access point in Android 10

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager

Im trying to get the mac address of the Access point to which my devices are connected  in Android 10 by

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) applicationContext.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getBSSID(); //always gets 02:00:00:00:00:00
```

as it is written  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo#getBSSID(), this result should only come, when im missing rights

i have the following permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

What else do i need?

This question has been asked before, but i only found answers that were years old and not working in Android 10.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is written https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo#getBSSID()

`getBSSID` returns `"02:00:00:00:00:00"`, if the caller has **insufficient permissions** to access the BSSID.

You have added following permissions in manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

But you need to take **runtime permission** for these above mentioned permission.

Please check Android Documentation from following URL to know how to implement runtime permission request.

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting